# Creating automatic unique ID in Survey123 for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123

I am working on Esri Survey 123 on a project.

I want to create an automatic unique ID of 6 numbers.

I can Make it by generating a unique password that consist of date and time: Example Date: 12/01/2017 Time: 12:05   ====>  Id= 120171205.

But can we do this in esri survey 123?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an existing enhancement request for this in Esri's Survey123Community at Github.

I recommend that you keep an eye on [Enhancement: Auto-Incrementing IDs  #302](https://github.com/Esri/Survey123Community/issues/302).

Answer (score 0):

You can use format-date
More info here: https://community.esri.com/groups/survey123/blog/2017/11/25/creating-ticket-numbers-in-survey123-for-arcgis